# Opening Pics sent through Text Message on my Nokia Lumia 1020

Tags: nokia-lumia-1020, mms

How do open pics sent to me through text message using my Nokia Lumia 1020. I get the message from the sending saying "Get media content now" 32K. When I touch it the statement reads "Getting media content", however; it doesn't upload. Please tell me how to set up the phone to open the pics

Comment: Are you able to send picture messages OK?

Comment: What carrier are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Data is turned on. I was using Wi-Fi and assumed this was good enough. When I turned Data on, the picture came through.

Answer (score 0):

Go to messaging settings and On the "Automatically download MMS" option On..This will help i guess

Comment: If it doesn't download when the OP selects Get Media Content, this will not help anything.